# MYSQL update not working with mutliple `AND` Statements

Tags: mysql

Here is the mysql code that I'm using:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE items SET Sort=? WHERE Id=? AND CharId = '{$CharacterId}' AND = ItemType = '{$ItemType}'");
```

Why isn't this working?

Answer (score 1):

You have extra "=" after your second AND.

Answer (score 0):

Buddy, Remove the extra **'='** sign before ITEMTYPE